# How to change the user after connecting to the jump host when using ProxyCommand

Tags: linux, ssh, ansible

My normal flow is like:

```
ssh jumphost
sudo -iHu jump_user
ssh target_user@targethost
Do some task
```

How to do this using ProxyCommand? I have tried:

```
ssh target_user@target_host -o ProxyCommand="ssh jumphost 'sudo -iHu jump_user' nc -w 120 %h %p"
```

But it's asking password for `target_user` as user is not changing to `jump_user` on `jump_host`. How to do it? My final aim is to use this as `ansible_ssh_common_args` so I can run tasks on target server.

Comment: What version of OpenSSH are you using? And why do you need to change user on the jump host?

Comment: @Kusalananda, It's 7.4

Comment: @Kusalananda, I can't directly ssh to target_host with my user, I need to ssh to the jumphost first, that also I can't ssh with jump_user. But I can run `sudo -iHu jump_user` and after that only I can ssh into target_host. It's security related, and I don't know much about it.

Comment: Is `jump_user` not able to use `ssh` from the `jumphost` host?

Comment: @Kusalananda No, that's where I'm also confused. I have to follow the above flow which asks no passwords. Can't ssh jump_user@targethost from jumphost or can't ssh jump_user@jump_host from myhost. Maybe some authorized_keys are setup.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me you only need:

```
ssh -t jumphost 'exec sudo -iHu jump_user exec ssh target_user@targethost'
```

`ProxyCommand` only gives you network connectivity, but if you need to switch user on `jumphost`, that suggests you need to access `jump_user`'s private key, in which case you do need to run `ssh` as that user over there.

Best would probably be to avoid that and add *your* own key to the `authorized_keys` of `target_user@targethost`, and then you can just do:

```
ssh -j jump_host target_user@targethost
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a `.ssh/config` file on the jumphost with:

```
Host targethost
  User target_user
```

Or whatever is appropriate for your setup.  Other settings like keepalives, agent forwarding, multiplexing etc can also be configured here to make your life easier.

`man ssh_config` is the documentation you want to consult.

Comment: The problem is on jump_host user is not changed to jump_user. Really sorry, it wasn't clear in my question. I have edited it.

Comment: So, `sudo -i` gives you an interactive shell - that's not what you want here.  Have you tried with something like `ssh jumphost 'sudo -u jump_user "ssh target_user@targethost do-some-task"'` ?  Get that form working, and then adjust your `.ssh/config`/proxy command based on it.

Answer (score 0):

I would change user as I connect to jumphost: `ssh jumpuser@jumphost`. To do this you need to set it up, by registering the public key on jumphost in `~jumpuser/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

## Alternatively

Copy the private key from jumpuser to youruser.
The lack of this key is the only explanation for ssh not working from youruser (the only explanation that results in the remote asking for a password).